# How to search ^A in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I have a text in vim like :

```
28473^A1619497837375
28473^A1619497837375
28474^A1619497837375
28474^A1619497837375
28474^A1619497837375
28474^A1619497837375
```

[image: shortcut]

How do I search the "^A" ?

Comment: The platform is ```windows10``` . The shell is ```windows terminal``` which uses wsl2 ubuntu20.04 shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search control characters by their decimal value:

```
/\%x01
```

See `:help \%x` and [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Basic_ASCII_control_codes).

Answer (score 3):

Due to the syntax highlighting in the screenshot it looks like `^A` is a control character.

If that's the case you can search for it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> after <kbd>/</kbd>.

Comment: How to type it on windows ? When I type ```ctrl``` ```v``` , It pastes things from my clipboard ...

Comment: @DachuanZhao `:h CTRL-V-alternative`

Comment: It is a control character, but you don't get it with Ctrl-v and then A. You need Ctrl-v and then Ctrl-a.

Comment: ```CTRL-V-alternative CTRL-Q
Since CTRL-V is used to paste, you can't use it to start a blockwise Visual
selection.  You can use CTRL-Q instead.  You can also use CTRL-Q in Insert
mode and Command-line mode to get the old meaning of CTRL-V.  But CTRL-Q
doesn't work for terminals when it's used for control flow.``` It shows this ......

Comment: When I use ```ctrl``` ```q``` then ```ctrl``` ```a``` , it shows strange characters all the screen .....

Comment: By the way , I use ```windows terminal``` on win10